# How do Doc2Vec PV-DBOW iterations/epoch's work?

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings, word2vec, doc2vec

Please correct me if I'm wrong but as I understand it, one iteration (?) of doc2vec takes each document and predicts a series of randomly sampled context words individually, feeding the errors from the prediction of each word back in to the network to adjust the weights.

- Does iteration 2 predict a second randomly sampled set of context words for each document?
- Does backpropagation only happen once for each predicted word/iteration combination?
- Does iteration 2 start with the final weights calculated in iteration 1? (if not, how are the findings/weights from iteration 1 and 2 combined?)